# What if the UpperBound column value is null?

Tags: t-sql

I have table called Product which has CreatedAt(Not Null, DateTime) and UpdatedAt Column(Nullable, DateTime).
I am trying to get Values which falls with in a certain date

The sql statement

```
Select [Id], [Name] FROM [dbo].[Product] where @Date Between CreatedAt AND UpdatedAt
```

It is returning less values than I am expected because in certain records, the UpdatedAt value is Null.

I have tried coalesce and is not null. But that did not work.
How can I resolve it?

Comment: where @Date between CreatedAt and isnull(UpdatedAt, '12/31/9999') .. or whatever date far in the future you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
Select [Id], [Name] FROM [Product] 
where 
   @Date Between CreatedAt AND isnull(UpdatedAt,@date)
```

The between operator returns true if the date is between or equal to the two interval dates, so if CreatedAt>@Date it returns false, even when UpdatedAt is null and the upper limit in the between will be @Date.

Test example:

```
declare @date date = cast('20100601' as date)
;with Product as
(
select [Id], [Name] ,[CreatedAt],[UpdatedAt] 
from
(values
(1,'Product 1',cast('20100101' as date),cast('20110101' as date))
,(2,'Product 2',cast('20100101' as date),null)
,(3,'Product 3',cast('20100701' as date),null)
) a([Id], [Name] ,[CreatedAt],[UpdatedAt])
)
Select 
    [Id], [Name] FROM [Product] 
where 
    @Date Between CreatedAt AND isnull(UpdatedAt,@date)
```